# Reading values as a list from ini file are picked at random

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ini

I have a problem reading some values from an ini file as a list. I have made a program which takes two lists as parameters (source, destination) and then copies the source paths to the destination paths. It gets these paths from an ini file called paths.ini. However, I noticed the values were not added in a chronological order, which meant that the first value in the ini file was not necessarily the first value in the list. This is a critical error, seeing as I want the first source to only be copied to the first destination.

Here is a sample code of what I have done:

```
try:
    src = list(dict(config.items('src')).values())
    dst = list(dict(config.items('dst')).values())
    print("src: "+ str(src) + " dst: "+ str(dst))


except Exception as e:
    messagebox.showerror("Data mismatch", "Mismatch between data from ini and core file")
    sys.exit(0)

if(utilFunctions.copyto(src, dst, True)):
    successCopy()
else:
    errorCopy()
```

For those wanting to see the ini file:

```
[src]
src1 = C:/Users/saUser/Documents/copyExample/singleCopies/1/2/3.txt
src2 = C:/Users/saUser/Documents/copyExample/singleCopies/1/2/3.txt


[dst]
dst1 = C:/Users/saUser/Documents/copyExample/singleCopies/1
dst2 = C:/Users/saUser/Documents/copyExample/singleCopies/1
```

Comment: Dictionaries in python (and indeed in most languages) are unordered. Why are you passing your `config.items('...')` calls through a `dict`, then casting it back to a list?

Comment: @Hamms my program takes two list (source, destination) as parameters. Do you know a better way I could get the values from the ini file in a way so the items are ordered?

Comment: @tomSurge A better way would be to enter all the sources/destinations in the same line, separated by a known character (',' for example), then simply reading and splitting that line. It will lead to both simpler code and being able to have a variable amount of sources and destinations without the need to change the code.

Comment: @tomSurge Yes, your program takes two lists. So why are you using a `dict`?

Comment: @Hamms Because I only need the values, if I simply do "list(config.items('src')) I also get the section name.

Comment: My point being that by casting `config.items` to a dictionary, you are losing its ordered nature. You should find a way to get the values you want out of that call without using a dictionary to do so. Jose's answer below provides one of many such ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using the builtin `ConfigParser`. According to the documentation, that is using a `collections.OrderedDict` to store the values in your files, so while the read is made sequentially, it should be okay and you end up with an ordered dictionary representing your file contents from a `[section]` top to the bottom.

If you want a list from that, just don't do that `list(dict(...` thing you are doing. Better use a list comprehension:

```
src = [value for key, value in config.items('src')]
dst = [value for key, value in config.items('dst')]
```

Then you will have what you want, ordered as well, in your `src` and `dst`.

Comment: Clean, understandable and elegant way of solving the problem. Thank-you.